# document.getElementById Hidden Text Not Visible for Bookmarks in Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript document.getElementById to change out images and hide and show text on a services landing page featuring 17 different services and expanded descriptions. As it is set up right now, the landing page opens with all the services closed and a plus image next to each heading row. When the user clicks on the image or the heading, the image changes to a minus and the text expands to reveal the hidden text. Once expanded, the user can click again on the image or the header and it will contract and appear as originally landed on.

Here is the script that I am using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function showHide(HID,IMG) {
    if (document.getElementById(IMG).src.indexOf('expand') != -1) {
    document.getElementById(IMG).src='../_media/images/common      
    /collapse.jpg';
    document.getElementById(HID).className='visibleRow';
    } else {
    document.getElementById(IMG).src='../_media/images/common
    /expand.jpg';
    document.getElementById(HID).className='hiddenRow';
    }
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

And here is the html that I am using (one row as an example):

```
    <tr bgcolor="#051846">
    <td>
    <img id="image2" border="0" src="../_media/images/common/expand.jpg" 
    onclick="showHide('divHidden2','image2');" style="cursor:pointer; 
    float:left; margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;" alt="" />&nbsp;
    <span style="font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 
    20px; font-weight:normal;color: #ffffff;cursor:pointer;line-height: 
    40px;font-variant: small-caps;margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;"  
    onclick="showHide('divHidden2','image2');">Buy/Sell Decisions</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="divHidden2" name="divHidden2" class="hiddenRow"><ul 
    class="hidden">
    <li>Corporate divestitures and purchases.</li>
    <li>Underwater resort in the Fiji Islands.</li>
    <li>High-end golf community in southern Spain.</li>
    <li>3,235-hectare multi-use commercial land subdivision in South    
    Africa.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to link the main menu from the home page to the services page creating an anchor for each hidden detail:

```
    <div id="divHidden2" name="divHidden2" class="hiddenRow">
```

On the home page and the menu is the listing of all the services, with an hyperlink to the services page and the anchor.

```
    <a href="services/services.shtml#divHidden2">
```

My process for creating the anchors appears to be working, however, I am not able to get the hidden text to be visible when the page is opened. I have looked at including javascript in the a href and many other approaches but nothing is able to direct someone from the home page to the services page with that specific service expanded. My initial page passed the W3C validation test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, adding CSS and Javascript on HTML page is not a good practice. 
how about using setAttribute method?

```
var img = document.getElementById('divID');
img.onclick = foo;
function foo(img) {
  img.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
}
```

I wish someone would told me this trick when I was stressing about W3 validation test. I just gave you the code to hide the code. You can find a way to show the image by setting style to display:block.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not working. The current programming changes the image in the heading and hides/shows the expanded text. Everything on the services page works with the current code as I want, when on the services page. I just need a way to tell it to expand when coming to the services page from another page. I hope that this clarifies the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain the answer to this question elsewhere and thought that I would post it here in the event that anyone else had a similar situation.

In the javascript itself, I needed to add:

```
    $(function() {
    // find out what our query parameters contain.
    var query = location.search;

     // isolate the position of the equal sign.
    var equalIndex = query.indexOf('=');
    // extract the image's id.
    var imageId = query.substring(equalIndex + 1);

    // click on the appropriate image.
    $('#' + imageId).click();
    });
```

I then needed to make the a href tie accordingly by changing it to:

```
    <a href="services/services.shtml?div=image17">
```

In essence, I was forcing an onclick to click so that the hidden text would be revealed upon opening. The difference is that it was tied to the image and not the div. I hope that this is beneficial to someone else.